# Plain text signature not applying

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010, I have a user whose plain text signatures do not embed into plain text messages on replies and forwards. Her HTML messages embedes the HTML signature just fine.  Plain text signature was created with Notepad and saved into %AppData%\Microsoft\Signatures (with all the other signatures). Anyone know of a reason why so I can troubleshoot/fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new profile under Control Panel --> Mail fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the signature in Outlook -> Options -> Mail -> Create or modify signatures for messages -> Replies/forwards is enabled or selected?

Brian Crawford
MxToolbox Inc.
mxtoolbox.com